# JQuery dynamically added button, text not in button

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I attempt creating buttons from jQuery, the text appears outside of the button element I created.  I've tried creating each button individually and as a group, and neither method seems to work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id = 'output_div'></div>

var main = function(){
    var selections = ['derp', 'herp', 'merp', 'foo'];


    //individually creating each button
    for(var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++){
        $('#output_div').append("<input type='button'>" + selections[i] +
          "</input>");
    };

    $('#output_div').append('<br><br>');


    //buttons all created at the same time
    var group_buttons = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++){
        group_buttons += ("<input type='button'>" + selections[i] + "</input>");
    };

    $('#output_div').append(group_buttons);
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fjr56Lsj/4/

Comment: input of type button has property called "value". You need to set it up. <input type="button" value="abc"/>

Comment: Sure. Fixed the issue here : https://jsfiddle.net/fjr56Lsj/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the button text either as the **`value` attribute of the `<input>`**, or **render the buttons as `<button>`**:

```js
$(function() {
  var selections = ['derp', 'herp', 'merp', 'foo'];

  for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
    $('#output_div').append("<input type='button' value='" + selections[i] + "' />");
  };

  $('#output_div').append('<br><br>');

  for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
    $('#output_div').append("<button>" + selections[i] + "</button>");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output_div'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to create a button using jquery would be as follows:

```
var dynamicButton = $('<button/>', {
    text: selections[i],
    id: 'dynamicButton_'+i
});
$('#output_div').append(dynamicButton);
```

Answer (score 1):

As input type button attribute , use value = selections[i] (keep Ur quotes careful) else use button tag instead input element

Answer (score 1):

The Button can be created in this fashion too:

```
$('<button/>', {
    text: selections[i]
 })
```

```js
var main = function() {
  var selections = ['derp', 'herp', 'merp', 'foo'];


  //individually creating each button
  for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {

    $('#output_div').append($('<button/>', {
      text: selections[i]
    }));
  };

  $('#output_div').append('<br><br>');
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output_div'>

</div>
```